# what is codecheck in gitconfig?

Tags: git, git-config

I have created several repository in Ubuntu, but when I do:

```
~/gittest1
~/gittest2
~/gittest3

vim ~/.gitconfig
```

I see:

```
user.name = Greatest Programmer
user.email = Greatest_programmer@stackoverflow.com
color.diff = auto
color.status = auto
color.branch = auto
codecheck.folder = /home/WorstSpeller/gittest1/tools/base/codecheck
```

so what exactly is codecheck and will it affect my other non-related git repositories?

Comment: This is rather unclear. An image, or more detail, would help greatly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`~/.gitconfig` is your global git config file, which will apply to any local repo.

It can evolve independently from a git repo creation: you can modify it at any time with a:

```
git config --global codecheck.folder xxx
```

There is no telling what application (like a [project CodeCheck?](https://github.com/TannerBaldus/codecheck)) has modified your global config spec, but you can safely ignore it for your created repos.